# HTML5 - css file

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make an html document and I am having some strange issue.
When the css file is in a different directory it works great but when I move the css file to the same directory as the html file it doesn't recognize it.

I changed the link href of the css.

Thanks for the help

OK sorry, I will elaborate- – 
When I use -

```
<title>Profile</title> 
<link href="./me_files/as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

it works. And when I move the file to the same folder and use

```
<title>Profile</title> 
<link href="as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

it doesn't work

OK I managed to fix it. The problem was that I needed to drop the- media="screen, handheld"

Thank you all!!!

Comment: What is the folders structure and what links do you set?

Comment: This post is useless without some example code.

Comment: please inform css link usages. Prob you are directing to root folder. Like "css/file.css" and "/file.css", second would not work.

Comment: post code buddy, unless we get the code we cant help with so less info..

Comment: upload your code in http://pastie.org/ here then only we will help to you otherwise useless this question

Comment: When I use -  <title>Profile</title>
    <link href="./me_files/as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> - it works             And when I move the file to the same folder and use -    <title>Profile</title>
    <link href="as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

> "When I use - `<title>Profile</title> <link href="./me_files/as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> - it works And when I move the file to the same folder and use - <title>Profile</title> <link href="as.css" media="screen, handheld" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` it doesn't work"

Have you tried

```
href="./as.css" ?
```

**EDIT**

Maybe you have some relative links inside your CSS that need to be changed?

Comment: I am aware that it should work without it, people... no need to get excited.

Comment: What part should I post? Thats the only change I made

Comment: Do you have links in your css? is everything well formed?

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/